# Dojo Mobile 1.8 on BlackBerry 6 - click on a dojox.mobile.ListItem only selects the item and does not fire the moveTo property

Tags: blackberry, dojo, dojox.mobile

I used http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/ as source to build my first mobile webapp with dojo mobile 1.8 and it works great on iOs and Android.

On Blackberry 6 (device 9300 - v 6.0.0.448, plattform 6.6.0.124 ) it doesn’t behave as expected in the default OS browser. The 'moveTo' property is not fired when I move the mouse pointer over a dojox.mobile.ListItem and click on it by pressing the touch pad (the standard behavior to open a link or press a button in the web browser with the BlackBerry 9300 on any other site).

I tried the demo apps provided on the dojo website under http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/demo/ and the demo under http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileFileBrowser/demo.html and both are showing the same issue with BlackBerry 9300: 
Clicking on an item only selects the item; you have to press enter on the keyboard after selecting the item to trigger the moveTo property.

**Is that the expected, normal behavior on BlackBerry devices with dojo 1.8? What can I do to trigger the moveTo property by clicking on it instead of selecting it and press return?**

Structure of my web app:

- dojox.mobile.View (id="home" data-dojo-props="selected: true")

  - dojox.mobile.Heading
  - dojox.mobile.RoundRectList
    *dojox.mobile.ListItem (data-dojo-props="moveTo: 'inbox'")
    *dojox.mobile.ListItem (data-dojo-props="moveTo: 'search'")
- dojox.mobile.View (id="inbox")

  - dojox.mobile.Heading (data-dojo-props="back:'Home', moveTo:'home'">
  - dojox.mobile.RoundRectList
    *dojox.mobile.ListItem 
    *dojox.mobile.ListItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is unfortunately a limitation up to Dojo 1.8: Dojo Mobile cannot handle both touch and mouse events (and the BB touch pad actually sends mouse events). This will be fixed in Dojo 1.9 (currently in beta, release should be available in early May).

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. Unfortunately I am forced to use dojo 1.8.1 because it is bundled with the used middle ware I used to build the app (IBM Domino 9.0 with Xpages). I will have a look around to find a solution to transform those mouse events to touch events or something like that.

Comment: I found a relevant ticket at bugs.dojotoolkit.org I share here for the people who want more details:
http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/13048